# Combining two seperate arrays each with a different number of elements

Tags: php, arrays

I'm becoming a little frustrated with my array results.  Ideally, I am creating a form maker module within my application and I am working with two different arrays to establish my database columns and excel columns.  Essentially, I am using the results provided by the arrays to write directly to a php file (Excel reader file).  In order to establish a difference in Excel Workbooks, I am putting forth an identifier "page2","page3" and so on within the "excel_rows" array.

```
//my arrays
$table_columns = array('field1','field2','field3','field4','field5'); //fields
$excel_rows = array('c1','c2','page2','c3','c4','page3','c5'); //excel columns
```

From here.. I go on to try to filter the array keys..

```
foreach(array_keys($excel_rows) as $key){
$page = array_search(strpos(trim($excel_rows[$key]),'page'),$excel_rows);
if(strpos(trim($excel_rows[$key]),'page') !== false){
$excel_row .= '$objTpl->setActiveSheetIndex('.(str_replace('page','',trim($excel_rows[$key])) -1).');<br/>'.PHP_EOL;
$table_columns[$key] = 0;
}
else {
$excel_row .= '$objTpl->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue(\''.trim($excel_rows[$key]).'\',$row[\''.trim($table_columns[$key]).'\']);<br/>'.PHP_EOL;
}
}

print $excel_row;
```

**The result should echo out the following:**

```
$objTpl->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue('c1', $row['field1']);
$objTpl->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue('c2', $row['field2']);
$objTpl->setActiveSheetIndex(1);<br/>
$objTpl->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue('c3', $row['field4']);
$objTpl->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue('c4', $row['field5']);
$objTpl->setActiveSheetIndex(2);
$objTpl->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue('c5', $row['']);
```

As one can see, I am missing 'field3' from my result and 'cs' produces and empty row rather than "field5".

I'm assuming something like array_compare or array_combine is the solution - I'm just not able to put it together.

Everything works lovely with module pardoning the array code above.  Any help with this would be sincerely appreciated!

-Regards.

Comment: the problem is field3 is on the same key as page2 and that's why the next field is field4 and not field3, since you're using the same key. Solution would be inserting an empty string on the same key as page commands.

Comment: Yeah..that part was a given.  Trying to determine if there is anyway to avoid having to provide an empty string for the "table_columns" at set-up/insert.

Comment: Wouldn't it better to create a multidimensional array? `array("page1" => array("c1, c2"), "page2" => array("c3", "c4"), "page3" => array("c5"));`

Comment: You're right.  However, these arrays are being established via form submission with comma separated values.  I am then creating the arrays from there.  If you have any suggestions with that, I'm all ears.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How it currently is I'd say you need to set an integer +1 whenever you create a new page and then subtract that integer from the key so you can get the right field.

```
$subkey = 0;
foreach(array_keys($excel_rows) as $key){
    $fieldkey = $key - $subkey;
    $page = array_search(strpos(trim($excel_rows[$key]),'page'),$excel_rows);
    if(strpos(trim($excel_rows[$key]),'page') !== false){
        $excel_row .= '$objTpl->setActiveSheetIndex('.(str_replace('page','',trim($excel_rows[$key])) -1).');<br/>'.PHP_EOL;
        //$table_columns[$key] = 0; I'm not sure what this is supposed to do
        $subkey++;
    }
    else {
        $excel_row .= '$objTpl->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue(\''.trim($excel_rows[$key]).'\',$row[\''.trim($table_columns[$fieldkey]).'\']);<br/>'.PHP_EOL;
    }
}

print $excel_row;
```

Comment: Sorry for the delayed response.  This is the correct answer.  Thank you!